# How do I change a Spritebuilder Scene in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, spritebuilder

I have a start menu ccb with a button that says "start." I just need it so that the player can click the start button and it takes them to my other ccb the "gameScene."

I'm using swift. How in do I accomplish this? I've been looking for the last couple hours and have yet to find an actual answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

First, make sure your SpriteBuilder's button has it's CCControl set to the method you want all your changing to happen in. You can find this by clicking on your button in SpriteBuilder and looking on the Code Connection tab on the side bar (the middle button that looks like an arrow).

I called mine "start." Then, in the scene class in XCode, create a method the same name name as what you put in the sidebar.

The rest should look like this:

```
func start() {
    var gameScene : CCScene =  CCBReader.loadAsScene("GameScene")
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(gameScene)
}
```

"GameScene" is the name of the scene I wanted to go to: `GameScene.ccp`.

Good luck!

EDIT: Make sure you also have a variable (doc root var) name for your button. I called my button "startButton." I'm honestly not sure if that causes a problem or not, but I added a name and it seemed to make things work.